# Autocomplete and suggesstion in QML textInput element

Tags: c++, qt, autocomplete, qml, pyside

I have a QML textInput element like this:

TextBox.qml

```
FocusScope {
    id: focusScope
    property int fontSize: focusScope.height -30
    property int textBoxWidth: parent.width * 0.8
    property int textBoxHeight: 45
    property string placeHolder: 'Type something...'
    property bool isUserInTheMiddleOfEntringText: false
    width: textBoxWidth
    height: textBoxHeight

    Rectangle {
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        border.color:'blue'
        border.width: 3
        radius: 0
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                focusScope.focus = true
                textInput.openSoftwareInputPanel()
            }
        }
    }
    Text {
        id: typeSomething
        anchors.fill: parent; anchors.rightMargin: 8
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        text: placeHolder
        color: 'red'
        font.italic: true
        font.pointSize: fontSize
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                focusScope.focus = true
                textInput.openSoftwareInputPanel()
            }
        }

    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            focusScope.focus = true
            textInput.openSoftwareInputPanel()
        }
    }

    TextInput {
        id: textInput
        anchors {
            right: parent.right
            rightMargin: 8
            left: clear.right
            leftMargin: 8
            verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        }
        focus: true
        selectByMouse: true
        font.pointSize: fontSize
    }



    Text {
        id: clear
        text: '\u2717'
        color: 'yellow'
        font.pointSize: 25
        opacity: 0
        visible: readOnlyTextBox ? false : true
        anchors {
            left: parent.left
            leftMargin: 8
            verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        }
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                textInput.text = ''
                focusScope.focus = true;
                textInput.openSoftwareInputPanel()
            }
        }
    }

    states: State {
        name: 'hasText'; when: textInput.text != ''
        PropertyChanges {
            target: typeSomething
            opacity: 0
        }
        PropertyChanges {
            target: clear
            opacity: 0.5
        }
    }

    transitions: [
        Transition {
            from: ''; to: 'hasText'
            NumberAnimation {
                exclude: typeSomething
                properties: 'opacity'
            }
        },
        Transition {
            from: 'hasText'; to: ''
            NumberAnimation {
                properties: 'opacity'
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to add autocomplete and suggestions like google search to this text box. Autocomple get data from database and database return a list of dictionaries by a pyside SLOT.(or c++ slot)

How I can do this work?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Take a look at this code: https://github.com/jturcotte/liquid/blob/master/qml/content/SuggestionBox.qml

I bet it will do the job.

**Edit:**

Code that linked above is somewhat complicated and requires C++ backend, so I simplified it and made pure Qml example application, that you can play with, edit a little and apply to your needs. Sources can be found [here](https://github.com/dant3/qmlcompletionbox). Most important things there are:

1. [This implementation of SuggestionBox](https://github.com/dant3/qmlcompletionbox/blob/master/SuggestionBox.qml) that uses some sort of *model* as it's source for completing/suggesting something
2. Its signal *itemSelected(item)* will be emitted every time user clicks on item
3. [Main component of application](https://github.com/dant3/qmlcompletionbox/blob/master/Main.qml) that [binds its LineEdit component to SuggestionBox](https://github.com/dant3/qmlcompletionbox/blob/master/Main.qml#L29)

Note that code is quite rough and written for a sake of example.

Comment: thanks.this suggestion is very good, but suggestions is not selectable  with mouse and keyboard Arrow keys.can you add it on your code?

Comment: please see my comment @dant3

Comment: @varahram see [this edit](https://gitorious.org/dant3-playground/qmlcompletionbox/commit/8c368ed758f1f50cb68338d854b0033994eeea6b/diffs/2a710d2539f005048a1633a49aefb8e6d81a195d)

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for something very similar: a QML autocomplete component built around [QML TextField](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-textfield.html), rather than the lower-level, more flexible but also more work intensive TextInput as in the question.

Since I could not find that, I implemented it. If anyone wants to use it: it's licensed under MIT and available as part of [an application](https://github.com/fairdirect/foodrescue-app) I am developing. You find the component in [`src/qml/AutoComplete.qml`](https://github.com/fairdirect/foodrescue-app/blob/master/src/qml/AutoComplete.qml), and the application may serve as usage example. Features:

- highlighting of autocompleted characters in bold, as in Google Search
- Key bindings (navigating with arrow keys, Return / Enter, Esc to close completion box, Esc Esc to unfocus)
- uses a simple `QStringList` as model for now, with the application showing how to update the model with live SQL database queries when the next key is pressed
- heavily documented code, so it should be easy enough to adapt

[image: autocomplete component screenshot]

Let me know if this is useful, I might then package it as a Qt [QPM package](https://www.qpm.io/packages/index.html) or even try to make it mature enough to be added to the QML UI library [KDE Kirigami](https://kde.org/products/kirigami/).

Comment: Hey, so did you end up releasing this as a package?

Comment: @Curtwagner1984 No, since you're the first one expressing any interest in that. But it's just one QML file, so copy&paste should do for now.

Comment: The problem with that is that its dependant on `Kirigami`

Comment: Yeah same here, I would love to use that but Kirigami dependency is a no go for me.